# Endless problems launching external activity - Resource Not Found

Tags: java, android, resources

Working on my first Android app here.  I've searched and tried everything I can think of, but no luck...

As part of my app I'm trying to incorporate a separate file chooser project.  I'm trying to keep the chooser separate so that it could be shared by a number of future projects.  In and of itself, it launches fine.  The problem is when I try to launch it from my main application I get a `Resources.NotFoundException`.  I've had problems with Class Not Found, which I think I've straightened out by including the chooser in the Java Build Path and included in the Android Manifest of the main app.

Main App Manifest:

```
<application ...    
    <activity android:name=".MyMainApp" ...
    <activity android:name=".MyOtherActivity" ...
    <activity android:name="com.didjit.filechooser.FileChooser"/>
</application
```

File Chooser is launched in main code by this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.didjit.filechooser.FileChooser.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_CHOOSE_SOURCE);
```

On the Chooser side of things, the resource that's not being found is `R.layout.main`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    browseToRoot();
    findViewById(R.id.btnDone).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

The error it throws is this:

```
: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.didjit.MyMainApp/com.didjit.filechooser.FileChooser}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001
...
12-27 18:07:00.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1961): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001
```

One thing that I'm suspicious of is `com.didjit.MyMainApp/com.didjit.filechooser.FileChooser`, as though it's treating the external project as a sub component.

Also, I'm worried I frelled-up the project configuration while wrestling with this.  Originally, the chooser class wasn't being found.  It seemed that having it listed under `Java Build Path / Projects` wasn't enough; I had to also include the class folder under `Java Build Path / Libraries`.  I also ran into the same trouble if I made the chooser project a library.

So then...  Why can the project's classes be found now but not the resources?  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

P.S.  This is in Eclipse, coding against API 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.didjit.filechooser.FileChooser.class);
```

with

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.didjit.filechooser.FileChooser");
```

They way you are currently doing it is telling the intent that the activity is inside your current project. That's why its not finding the external resources. The way I am suggesting is the standard way to open an external application.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexPaino, That was essentially it!  I created a new intent with the action `com.didjit.filchooser.intent.action.SELECT_ACTION`.  Then added this as a public string (named SELECT_ACTION) to the FileChooser class.  Finally, the calling class uses `new Intent(FileChooser.SELECT_ACTION)`.  Thanks for straightening me out!

Answer (score 0):

None of these work for me. I found another approach to that problem.

You can use:

```
Intent i = new Intent("Whatever");
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.didjit.filechooser","com.didjit.filechooser.FileChooser"));
startActivity(i);
```

Where "com.didjit.filechooser" is your package name and "com.didjit.filechooser.FileChooser" is a name of Activity which you want to start.